# Searching for \n and \t

Tags: c++, binary, ascii

I'm trying to build a program able to read all the characters including control characters and whitespaces in a jpg file .... i made it read \n or \t but i can't add there both together or any other control character ...
here's my code..

```
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
  int main(){
  ifstream file("E:\\2.jpg", ios::binary);      
  string myString;
  ofstream fout("E:\\mnmn.txt");
while(getline(file,myString,'\n') )
  {
for (size_t i = 0; i < myString.size(); ++i)  
 {
  fout <<"."<< bitset<8>(myString.c_str()[i]);
}}
 return 0;
 }
```

Anyone can help ?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: `while(getline(file,myString,'\n') )`  How is this going to work if the data within the file can contain control characters?

Comment: Ok actually this code gives characters that isn't printable like 00001010 and the \t gives me 00001001

Comment: @MarkRansom my problem is i can't print out all the jpg as binary .. the control characters is missed

Comment: `\n` == 00001010 and `\t` == 00001001 are usually considered to be printable, although they are in the control code range of ASCII.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
while(getline(file,myString,'\n') )
{
   for (size_t i = 0; i < myString.size(); ++i)  
   {
      fout <<"."<< bitset<8>(myString.c_str()[i]);
   }
}
```

to

```
int c;
while( (c = file.get()) != EOF )
{
   fout <<"."<< bitset<8>(c);
}
```

Comment: 'struct std::ifstream' has no member named 'getc'

Comment: Sorry, that should've been `get()`. Fixed the answer.